# Remove non-object From List<Object>

Tags: java, list, object

As topic states, I want to remove non-objects from List of objects.

I have a web service (xml file with some data) and generated classes from XSD file. Among generated XSD classes there is a class `ASMENYS` and it has method `getContent()`. This method returns a list of generated.ASMUO objects.

Now the problem is, that this method for some reason returns empty lines (spaces?) among objects. I need to iterate through `asmenysList`, and because of empty spaces I'm forced to use `if()` which deprecates my code performance...Any ideas? Why are those empty spaces generated? Or maybe some ideas how to better filter them without iteration if possible?

```
//m here is generated.ASMENYS object,.: generated.ASMENYS@10636b0
List<Object> asmenysList = ((ASMENYS) m).getContent();
System.out.println(asmenysList);
```

---

```
[
, generated.ASMUO@1799640, 
, generated.ASMUO@b107fd, 
, generated.ASMUO@10636b0, 
...
, generated.ASMUO@1df00a0, 
]
```

---

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "", propOrder = {
"content"
})
@XmlRootElement(name = "ASMENYS")
public class ASMENYS {

@XmlElementRef(name = "ASMUO", type = ASMUO.class, required = false)
@XmlMixed
protected List<Object> content;

/**
 * Gets the value of the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * This accessor method returns a reference to the live list,
 * not a snapshot. Therefore any modification you make to the
 * returned list will be present inside the JAXB object.
 * This is why there is not a <CODE>set</CODE> method for the content property.
 * 
 * <p>
 * For example, to add a new item, do as follows:
 * <pre>
 *    getContent().add(newItem);
 * </pre>
 * 
 * 
 * <p>
 * Objects of the following type(s) are allowed in the list
 * {@link ASMUO }
 * {@link String }
 * 
 * 
 */
public List<Object> getContent() {
    if (content == null) {
        content = new ArrayList<Object>();
    }
    return this.content;
}

}
```

**EDIT**

```
/**
 * Gets the value of the asmId property.
 * 
 */
public int getAsmId() {
    return asmId;
}

List<Object> asmenysList = ((ASMENYS) m).getContent();
for(Object asm : asmenysList){
    //trying to cast empty asmenysList element, gives me an error.
    //that's why I'm forced to use if() as I said before.
    if(asm.getClass().getName() == "generated.ASMUO"){
        int asm_id = ((ASMUO) asm).getAsmId();
    } 
}
```

Comment: what version of Java are you using, 7 or 8?

Comment: For string comparation use "generated.ASMUO".equals(asm.getClass().getName()). 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java
As you have use it always will be false.

Comment: thanks, but @Elliott Frisch pointed that out already.

Answer (score 2):

By definition a `List<Object>` only holds `Object`(s). If there are primitive types in there, they must be autoboxed. If it's an array, that is an `Object`. The only *empty spaces* I see are from the `toString()` method of `List`.

**Edit**

based on your edit,

```
if(asm.getClass().getName() == "generated.ASMUO"){
```

Is not how you test String equality,

```
if(asm.getClass().getName().equals("generated.ASMUO")) {
```

Comment: What do you mean by saying that empty spaces are from toString() of List? Are you saying  toString() is used on an empty object or something like that?

Comment: @CrazySabbath `System.out.println(asmenysList);` calls `toString()` on `asmenysList` which in turn concatenates calls to `toString()` on the elements in the `List`.

Comment: That's true, but I only used `.println` here to show you what getContent() outcome. I'll edit my question with more explanation.

Comment: Yes, you might be right (your EDIT), but either way works just fine. Problem is I don't want to do that, I'd rather getContent() returned data without empty spaces..or filter it before iterating.